# Flash ActionScript 3.0 - Any free compiler, tools and tutorials?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, youtube-api, flvplayer

I have got an assignment in which I have to implement a AS3 wrapper for any FLV player and I have to expose actionscript functions (External Interfaces?) so that other can be used in other different applications via CallFunction API. I have few questions regarding this -

1. Are the tools for this are freely available? I know Flex SDK is but I want standalone swf (I means Flash Player 10) that can be used anywhere without any dependency and should contain FLV player embedded or should be able to load it from a particular location by supplying the URL.
2. Is it possible only with an ActionScript compiler (or any free tools?). My problem is that I don't have flash or flex builder and I don't want to spend money on these because I don't work on it.
3. As I have almost zero knowledge about it. Can you guys please explain me (if possible with details) that what I need to do. Any resoures on how to create and compile?
4. If any of you have ever done this it would be really great if you guys can share samples. I've heard that many people have done the same thing for video players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can share a bit of my setup

I use Flash (CS5) for creating assets

I use FlexSDK as the compiler

And do all the code in FlashDevelop

Flashdevelop is for PC only for now, it's free and comes since the last few versions now with a debugger

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It seems interesting. Can you please share info that how can I set it up?
@Alex, Daniel - It would be really great if you can provide me quick tutorial about compiling AS files using Flex SDK? I have heard that they are not standalone and they need flex runtime. Is it true? I am looking for generating a simple swf that can be embedded anywhere.
BTW, I have found a link similar to problem:
http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/news/using-the-youtube-player-api-with-actionscript-30/

I think I should give it a try using Flex SDK if it can create Flash player based SWF. (?)

Answer (score 0):

I use FlexSDK to compile and Eclipse with AS IDE or something along those lines, and then preview things in a web browser using an html page with the swf file embedded.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me by sharing the details about cost and how to set it up?

Comment: Cost: None; IDE: Eclipse 3.6 from eclipse.org; AS3 plugin found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/as3ide/ FlexSDK found online (on Adobe's site, do a google search)  This lets me continue to do 99% of the coding I do in Eclipse (I do single source stuff in Vim and Bada OS development in Bada IDE (which is based off Eclipse))

Answer (score 0):

check out [projectsprouts](http://projectsprouts.org/). its a pretty nice Flash (as2/3/Flex/AIR) generation tool that can help you stub out your project, compile it, and even create unit tests if you want. pretty simple ruby install (i am a ruby newb, and got is running pretty easily). It was a pretty good support base, and an active mailing list where people will be happy to help you along.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that the **FlexSDK** has very little to do with **Flex** unless you are linking against classes that are Flex specific. **mxmlc** does **not** have anything to do with **MXML** even though it will also compile MXML.

[Here is an article](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/wordpress/?p=78) that describes Flash development on Linux. It is pretty old, but the principles are the same. With an Actionscript 3 Compiler (contained in the FlexSDK) and a text editor, you are off to the races. It is a lot easier with Flash Builder 4, FDT 4, Intellij IDEA, Flash Develop, etc ;)